# Can you please let me know how to configure liberty server to deploy Ant build war file

Tags: ant, websphere-liberty

Can someone let me know steps to configure Liberty server to automatically pick the ant build war file from specified location within project folder and deploy the same under liberty server runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Liberty Ant tasks defined at the [WASdev/ci.ant](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.ant) project, you could deploy a WAR with something like this:

```
<project xmlns:wlp="antlib:net.wasdev.wlp.ant" name="net.wasdev.wlp.ant.it">

    <path id="wlp-ant-tasks.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/../../../../target" includes="wlp-anttasks-*.jar" />
    </path>
    <typedef resource="net/wasdev/wlp/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:net.wasdev.wlp.ant" classpathref="wlp-ant-tasks.classpath" />

    <property name="target.dir" value="${basedir}/../install-server-it/target" />

    <!-- Defining server configuration -->
    <property name="wlp.install.dir" value="${target.dir}/wlp" />
    <property name="wlp.usr.dir" value="${target.dir}/wlp_usr" />
    <property name="wlp.output.dir" value="${target.dir}/wlp_output" />
    <property name="servername" value="deploy.war" />

    <target name="deploy">
        <wlp:server id="testServer" installDir="${wlp.install.dir}" serverName="${servername}" userDir="${wlp.usr.dir}" outputDir="${wlp.output.dir}" operation="status" />

        <wlp:server ref="testServer" operation="start" />

        <wlp:deploy ref="testServer">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/../../setup/test-war/target">
                <include name="*.war" />
            </fileset>
        </wlp:deploy>
    </target>
</project>
```

You can get the **wlp-anttasks-*.jar** from Maven Central [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/wasdev/wlp/ant/wlp-anttasks/1.6/wlp-anttasks-1.6.jar) or build it locally by cloning the [WASdev/ci.ant](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.ant) project and doing a Maven build.

Note:  I took the example above from the integration test [here](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.ant/blob/master/src/it/tests/deploy-war-it/build.xml).  See the documentation [here](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.ant/tree/master/docs) for more details on the tasks and their attributes, etc.

Comment: This answer assumes you want to deploy using an Ant build.   However, one could also interpret your question as "I did an Ant build to build the WAR, now I just want to deploy it somehow."   If the latter is the case, you could use the **maven-antrun-plugin** within a Maven project that uses the **liberty-maven-plugin** developed at [WASdev/ci.maven](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven)